# WinSCP NuGet package .NET Standard error

Tags: .net, .net-standard, winscp, .net-standard-2.0, winscp-net

I am trying to build a **.NET Standard 2.0 Class Library** that uses the `WinSCP NuGet` package. However, when I install the package even though it adds it as a dependency I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'WinSCP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

when:

```
using WinSCP
```

By manually adding the `WinSCPnet.dll` as a reference this fixes the error, but this is causing issues with building the library in Bamboo so I was wondering if there is another way I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.NET Standard is supported since WinSCP 5.15](https://winscp.net/tracker/1640) only.

It's not supported by the earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will give the beta a go. Do you have an eta on the release of 5.14?